# can't change color with CSS

Tags: html, css

oke so i heard that the css code is fine. so here is the html code i use

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
 <html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <title>The White Stripes!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
    </head>
<body background="white.jpg">

<h1 style="color:white;">Welom op de White Stripes Website van Max Wijtmans</h1>
<h3 style="color:white;">Op deze website kunt u heel veel informatie van de band Seven Nation Army halen. U kunt ook contact met mij opnemen als u dat wilt.
<br/><h3 style="color:white;">hier een filmpje van hun grootste hitSeven Nation Army</h3> <br/> <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0J2QdDbelmY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>
<ul>
<li> <a href="weetjes.html" target="blank">weetjes over de band</a>
<li> <a href="geschiedenis.html" target="blank">de geschiedenis van deband</a>
<li> <a href="albums.html" target="blank">alle albums van de band</a>
```

<

```
</body>
 </html>
```

it does end with /body and /html but i cant get it in this post sorry for that. oh and i am dutch so please ignore the dutch sentences

Comment: please show us code with html or possible live example, i think your other css code overriding this

Comment: Could you put this on jsfiddle or at least provide your HTML code as well?

Comment: Are you saying the page doesn't load your style sheet? If so you might want to show people how you reference your style sheets and where they are located in your file structure

Comment: I'm with NullPoiиteя - we need more information. My initial thought would be that the style tags are not pointed to the right file, hence why no style is being passed.

Comment: Please post a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Because [your code obviously works](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/b1cw7e0o/), so there has to be more.

Comment: If you are writing CSS code into a CSS file then you don't have to user  <style></style> tag, as Its a HTML tag and not CSS's. So remove that tag and then check again.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have the CSS in a separate file, but it still starts with `<style>`. In this case the start of the CSS file looks like this:

```
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
```

The browser then interprets this as a selector `<style> a:link`, which obviously doesn't match any element.

The `<style>` tags are only necessary, when you put the CSS directly into the HTML instead of loading it with a `<link>`.

**Edit:** After you edited your question: Are you sure, that the stylesheet is loaded at all? Put this at the very top of the stylesheet:

```
* { background: pink !important; }
```

Does everything get pink? If not, try to fix the `href` in the `<link>` element, until you see a pink page.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you already have the separate .css file located somewhere with your .html file.

Including HTML code in your CSS file is breaking it, so make sure you don't use `<style>` tags in your .css file.

Second, you would like to check if your CSS file is linked to your HTML page correctly:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Make sure it is in your `<head>` section and that the `href` points to a right directory and file.

Otherwise your CSS code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you included the css file but here is how you should do it. The html file should have the `link` tag inside the `head`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">This is my test</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `style.css` file must be added in the root folder of your site (you might consider changing it to a public assets folder). The only thing the css file should contain for this example to work is:

```
a {
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```